# Will an observer falling into a black hole be able to witness any future events in the universe outside the black hole?

Tags: black-hole, horizon

I know someone or something sucked into a black hole could not survive, but is the bending of light so immense that an observer falling into a black hole will be able to witness any future events in the universe? That would definitely be cool :D I have a feeling this won't work though... so could you explain in detail why? Thanks.

Comment: Hello? This question is over 3 years old. Plus, that other question is almost a year newer than this one. Check the dates next time, please.

Comment: Timtech, it's fine to do so if the newer question has answers (especially if they're much better answers); see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/274942)

Comment: First off, these are significantly different questions. Plus, my answer (score 9) was suddenly deleted by some moderator. Is there a necro delete going on or something? Can't find enough work to do with newer questions, so you have to revisit older ones?

Comment: @Timtech I am not omniscient. I rely on the community's help to moderate. When the community flags a post that is in violation of the community rules (["Quote only the relevant portion" "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it."](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)), it is my job to request that it be amended--and if it is not in a timely manner, to delete it.

Comment: @Timtech Also, if you have been targeting downvotes, be aware that these are tracked in the system and will be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion about finite or infinite time dilation at the Schwarzschild radius began since Karl Schwarzschild in 1915 used a space-time coordinate system where coordinate time went to +∞ when a falling object approached the Schwarzschild radius. But *t* → +∞ for a world line that approaches the horizon is a thing different from *t* → +∞ far from the black hole. An object that is about to cross the horizon is in no position to synchronize clocks with an outside world.

**No,** completely opposite situation to the OP’s expectations. If a falling observer will *transmit* a powerful beam of light out of the hole, then photons will reach increasingly far future of the exterior universe. But the future *seen* by the falling observer will be very limited; see http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose_schw.html for graphic depiction.

Comment: The only people who are still confused about the difference between coordinate and true singularities are at most beginning students. So it is not clear about _who s_ confusion the first sentence talkes about; working physicists can not be meant.

Comment: @Dilaton: some people trying to understand black holes become confused. And not necessarily about “coordinate singularity” in Schwarzschild’s coordinates, but generally about clock synchronization with a falling object. I do not see how your comment about supposed “working physicists” is helpful.